Moving Rows Back and Forth Between Sheets When Checked (or unchecked)
I've very novice to Apps Script and coding in general.
This is a follow-up questions derived from Disappearing Rows When Moving on Checked.
I found this code online somewhere for moving rows between sheets whether or not a checkbox in a column is checked. I just changed a few things such as the names of the sheets and the column its looking at.
There is something wrong with it. Right now it seems to be moving the rows over to the other sheet, but when I uncheck the box to move it back, it sometimes disappears. Or it will move back and a different row will be deleted.
Also, lines 3 and 4 are no longer in use. It says "unused declaration for mainSheet' and the same for 'sheetToMoveTheRow' I'm a bit baffled by this because when the name of the function was onEdit it didn't give me the error, but I changed the function name to moveChecked and since then it has given me the issue.
function moveChecked() {

  var mainSheet = "To Do";
  var sheetToMoveTheRow = "Completed";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if(sheet.getName() == "To Do" && range.getColumn() == 1 && range.getValue() == true) {
    var row = range.getRow();
    var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    sheet.deleteRow(row);}
  
  else if(sheet.getName() == "Completed" && range.getColumn() == 1 && range.getValue() == false) {
    var row = range.getRow();
    var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("To Do");
    const aVals = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,targetSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
    const targetRow = aVals.filter(String).length + 1;
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetRow , 1);
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target); 
    sheet.deleteRow(row);}
    
}

I previously changed the name of the function from onEdit to moveChecked and I also deleted the triggers associated with it.

If you are adapting code created by someone else, you should give proper attribution, i.e., you might include the link from the webpage from were you taken the code and mention the name of the author.

As I have answered your previous question, I know that you are using a trigger. As each question should be self-contained, you should include data about the installable trigger so readers do not have to guess what kind of trigger you are using; it might be an edit or on-change installable trigger. Knowing the type of trigger is relevant because each one has a different event object. Also an on change trigger might be triggered by other actions.

This works for me:
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("Gate1");
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
    
  }
  else if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("Gate2");
    e.range.setValue("FALSE")
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
    const aVals = tsh.getRange(1, 1, tsh.getLastRow()).getValues();
    const targetRow = aVals.filter(String).length + 1;
    var trg = tsh.getRange(targetRow, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}

But if it doesn't work for you and you are using array forumulas on the sheet you're writing to then please know that array formulas can cause problems with sheet.getLastRow() method.

Regarding

Also, lines 3 and 4 are no longer in use. It says "unused declaration for mainSheet' and the same for 'sheetToMoveTheRow'

The referred code lines were not included in the question. You should have included them as well as the textual error message.
On the other hand, considering the code in the question, you should train your spreadsheet users not to check / uncheck checkboxes while another user is doing the same thing. Also, after checking / unchecking a checkbox, users should wait until the execution ends before checking / unchecking another checkbox.
In other words, you should train users to avoid running multiple executions simultaneously.
If you are the only user, this might not be a big deal, but if you share the spreadsheet with others, it might be better to choose another code source designed to be used by multiple users simultaneously and have the proper safeguards for that.
